# How can I use user input to call user defined function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, user-defined-functions

I have the following functions

```
def retrieve_phone_data():
    # function does something
    return phone_list

def retrieve_customer_data():
    # function does something
    return customer_info

def main(input1, input2):
    if input1 == 'phone' and input2 == 'customer':
        retrieve_phone_data()
        retrieve_customer_data()
    else:
        print('Please enter valid input')
```

`input1` and `input2` can only have specific values (lets say `"phone"` and `"customer"` for now). I have 10+ functions, I don't want to use If statements because it will be too much.

I need something like vlookup from excel, I will create the possible list of inputs and cosponsoring functions so that each valid user input will be linked to a function in that list. Is there a way to do?

Comment: The gist of your question is kind of clear, but your code example, apart from having incorrect indentations (which I submitted an edit for), is probably also not what you intended. You probably wanted to invoke `retrieve_phone_data` if `input1 == 'phone'` and invoke `retrieve_customer_data` if `input2 == `customer'`, rather than only invoke both functions if both equality conditons hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `dict` here:

```
data_retrievers = {
    "phone": retrieve_phone_data,
    "customer": retrieve_customer_data,
}
```

Then in your main method:

```
if input in data_retrievers:
    data_retriever = data_retrievers[input]
    retrieved_data = data_retriever()
else:
    # Signify invalid input
```

If you want to add another input, you just add an entry to `data_retrievers`, with the key being `input` and the value being the corresponding function. Note the lack of `()` after the function names in `data_retrievers`, the function is only called when `data_retriever` is fetched.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked smoothly. By the way I included data_retrivers in my main function. It is working smoothly. Cheers!